# MySQL returning only part of results from FULL TEXT SEARCH after version 5.6 to 5.7 upgrade

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I have a query that consists of two full text searches in boolean mode (combined with `OR` operator) that worked just fine on MySQL 5.6 and that fails after bumping MySQL version 5.7. Both DBs have the exact same set of records, both are hosted on AWS (InnoDB, aurora).

Query below (don't pay too much attention to the table/column names as I tried to anonymise them):

```
SELECT
    cars.id
FROM cars
         INNER JOIN driver_licenses ON driver_licenses.car_id = cars.id
         INNER JOIN drivers ON drivers.id = driver_licenses.driver_id AND drivers.noobie_driver = 0
WHERE (
              (MATCH(cars.name) AGAINST ('mark*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
              OR (MATCH(drivers.first_name, drivers.last_name, drivers.email) AGAINST ('mark*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
          );
```

Of course I have the fulltext index on the [first_name, last_name, email] columns, as well a btree index on `noobie_driver`. There are two indices on `cars.name` - one btree and the other one fulltext.

**Before** the upgrade, query returned proper results (counted in hundreds compared to a few million records in total).

**After** the upgrade - it seems that the query/optimizer focuses only on the first condition and completely disregards the second full text search (by driver's names and email) and returns only few records - related directly to the search result of `cars.name`.

When queries are ran separately (first time for `cars.name` and then for drivers details) and then combined, they return same results as before the upgrade.
Also when I force to ignore `noobie_driver` index (or remove the `noobie_driver` condition), both full text search conditions are taken into consideration.

Running `EXPLAIN` in both DBs return the same results.

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                        | key                                               | key_len | ref                                                 | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | drivers                   | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,index_drivers_on_noobie_driver                                                               | index_drivers_on_noobie_driver                    | 1       | const                                               | 6798 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | driver_licenses           | NULL       | ref    | index_driver_licenses_on_car_id,index_driver_licenses_on_driver_id                                   | index_driver_licenses_on_driver_id                | 5       | Rental.drivers.id                                   |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cars                      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                              | PRIMARY                                           | 4       | Rental.driver_licenses.car_id                       |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

<strike>Tomorrow I'll be working on rebuilding the index/table(s) to see if that brings any changes to the behaviour on 5.7, once it's done I'll come back with more details.</strike> Running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on all 3 tables haven't fixed anything here.

I'm wondering:

1. Have I missed something and it is a feature now in 5.7 now that it behaves this way?
2. How to overcome the issue and keep the exact same query (so without ignoring the index or performing two separate queries to combine the results afterwards)?

Comment: Where is the Explain plan? Have you rebuilt the indices since the upgrade?

Comment: @symcbean I updated the original post, both with EXPLAIN and information, that after running the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` it still behaves the same

Answer (score 0):

OK, dropping and recreating the index on `noobie_driver` column seems to do the trick on smoke-environment database that contains just few thousands records in the `drivers` table

```
DROP INDEX index_drivers_on_noobie_driver ON drivers;

CREATE INDEX index_drivers_on_noobie_driver USING BTREE ON drivers(noobie_driver);
```

**BUT with production data that handles ~2kk records in the `drivers"` table, dropping and recreating an index did not help. I'm starting to believe it could be related to some bug strictly related to MySQL version.**

Will be updating the question once I learn something new